# How to access a unit of a resource pool for condition in function

Tags: anylogic

I am currently utilizing a hold block to restrict agent of type `Patient` passing to a seize block. Upstream in the model, `Patient` are assigned only 1 unit of `Doctor` that it will interact with downstream in the model every time is seizes `Doctor` (This is shown in photo one, in the `Doctor` resource pool).

The problem is that I would like to access this particular unit of `Doctors` in a function that I have, in order to check if that specific unit of `Doctor` is idle. Photo 2 is the function im using at the moment, and I would like to add this solution as the third condition in the if statements. It already checks if an Surgeon is available, but I need to add a check to see if their specific `Doctor` is available.

Photo 1
[image]

Photo 2
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of a pool have to be accessed using the functions specific to them, and not their resource pool. Here, to check if the desired doctor is available, the third condition would be

myPatient.doctor.isIdle() == true

Answer (score 1):

Why does `agent.doctor` not work? Or did you not try it?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly didn't understand why you need to use a Hold block? After all, if the resource (`Doctors`) is busy, it will not be assigned to your agent (`Patient`).